# Could a world exist where Heaven functions and Hell dosen’t?

Tags: science-fiction, fantasy-races, alternate-reality

I’m thinking of a kinda weird story idea.
Basically, think of Jurrasic Park, but with demons instead of dinosaurs.

Basically, this is a universe where the Biblical Heaven and Hell existed, but almost the entire population of Hell was wiped out in a war with Heaven before the events of the present day.

Living humans can travel to either Heaven or Hell through special circumstances, such as Dante in the Inferno.

Hell functioned similarly to Dante’s Inferno, where there a multiple circles, or planes, and the souls of mortals were tortured for the sins they committed in life.

When good people die, they go to Heaven, while bad people go to Hell.

Basically, the demons are fallen angels, whose punishment is to torture the souls of the wicked for all of eternity.

But the demons are eventually cloned back into existence. I would like to know, could a world with a Heaven, and no Hell function?

Comment: Are you asking from a worldbuilding, or from a theological point of view?

Comment: You need to give us more rules to work with. Right now you're leaving enough room for anything from the Wild West to the First Order to happen. 
Also, can people just visit from place to another (like not die, just pop off to hell to check things out for a bit)?
Do people go to hell when they die? Or is it just people going to heaven and the rest of the souls being discarded into the void/purgatory?

Comment: I’ve added a bit more context, sorry about that.

Comment: How are the sinners being judged? who is the judge? Actually what happened to the judge?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a story-based question.

Comment: Can you explain why you think a world with a Heaven but no Hell might function any differently than our current world?

Comment: (1) There is precious little about Hell in the Bible. So it would definitely be nice to have a description and a citation about what *"Biblical Hell"* is supposed to be. (2) The opinions of Christian theologians vary very widely on whether anybody goes to Hell, and if some souls do go to Hell are they many or very few, and even on whether Hell is a place or simply a state of separation from God. (3) Which means that the question must specify clearly what is meant by Hell, because it cannot rely on the non-existent consensus of Christian viewpoints, much less on a world-wide consensus.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to definitively answer yes or no, because there's just so many different conceptions of heaven and hell just in Christianity, let alone in other religions that have those concepts.  Your idea may work fine as is in some ideologies, it may work after a few tweaks in some ideologies, and it may be totally impossible in some ideologies.  The problem with questions about deities and the afterlife is that we have very little real world info to base any answers on.

With this in mind, here's one reason why I think your idea would work, and one why I think it would not work.

It could work, because in real life, some Christians think Hell may be empty.  Their logic being that an all-merciful God wouldn't condemn anyone, no matter how evil, to eternal punishment.  Another not uncommon belief is that Hell is empty, save for Satan and his fallen angels.  The argument being something along the lines of "They should have known better."

On the other hand, demons and angels are eternal in some Christian denominations.  They're outside time, so from our point of view, fallen angels like Satan were never outside Hell.  So how can you do anything to them, i.e. clone them?  I hope I explained this well enough, but the gist is that time doesn't work like you expect it to when we're talking about angels, demons, and God; which means it's not clear that demons could be wiped out or cloned.

Answer (score 0):

In Short answer, Yes, however, this also brings up questions of how and why?

You see, the entire biblical sense in angels and god is that they care for all life, including the demons, even if they curse their lords name.

Now, why would heaven essentially wipe out an entire species, aka demons, and then bring them back? Angels are seen as the direct opposite of demons, thus in their nature to essentially Be enemy’s, but like I said, even if angels would harbinger hatred towards said demons, they’ll still consider them living beings, thus cloning them back in a zoo like environment.

This rises another question, where do the souls of those that committed murders and blasphemed against god, go? Answer is, they still go to hell, or better yet, the zoo hell, but without trying to explain why, let’s get into the conclusion

In conclusion, just think of hell and heaven as two different species, both are conflicting with each other, but if one Ceased to be, then it would only benefit the other. Also, if we are going off of the Christian bible, ( which is up to you ), then hell is just A byproduct of a rebellious angel, so hell, in this sense needs heaven to exist, because without it, then it wouldn’t exist.

Answer (score 0):

Some options for a Dante-style heaven without a Dante-style hell

### The Unrighteous (and Maybe the Righteous) Dead Slumber

There's precedent (Matthew 9:24, Luke 8:52) that the dead slumber until a final resurrection and judgement at the end of time. Maybe this only applies to the unrighteous. Maybe this is only true since hell has been closed.

### Purgatory is Filling

Dante described purgatory as a place almost without limit. It could be this is now the place for all those who can not make it to heaven. Like Scrooge's partner Marley in Charles Dickens' 'A Christmas Carol', the most terrible dead may be tied down with self-inflicted injuries to their souls that they unwittingly did during life. As such, their might be ghettos in purgatory where the worst have settled, unable to rise any further.

### Punishment and Rehabilitation

It's possible that some mechanism like C.S. Lewis's 'The Great Divorce' is still sending missionary expeditions from heaven attempting to rehabilitate lost souls in Purgatory. Maybe this was part of hell's job back in the day, but went undocumented. Dante's hell seemed much more about punishment than rehabilitation.

### Hell is Still Filling, Just Not Churning

Neil Gaiman provided a Dante-ish description of hell in 'Lucifer'. The denizens of hell may have gone to extra lengths to torment those souls that descended their, but decent into hell was a natural mechanic of guilt.

In this case, souls are still descending into hell; but there is no force taking them out of their 'What Dreams May Come' self-torture and aggravating it. In a way, hell sleeps uneasily, but sleeps.

### The Dead Walk The Earth

Even in Dante's telling, the dead walking on Earth were invisible to the living. With hell out of business, these dead may walk the Earth invisibly - seen and heard only in dreams and whispers.